# Convert last symbols of the URI to query string with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, server

I need to convert such url: "api/photo/5" to "api/photo/?id=5". I'm not really good in .htaccess so I need help in implementing this.
Is there a way to do like that?

Comment: please provide your .htaccess and what framework you are using.

Comment: mod_rewrite documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/photo/(\d+)$ /api/photo/?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```